# Send .txt through Bluetooth in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have this code, where I create a .txt file, and I would like to send it to another mobile phone already paired, but when I click on the button it does not open the bluetooth device window for me to select and send the respective file

I get this 2 error:

- Fail to get file list com.example.apptest
- getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

```
 public void sendData(){
        String sensorName = tvSensorName.getText().toString();
        String s1 = tvS1.getText().toString();
        String s2 = tvS2.getText().toString();
        String s3 = tvS3.getText().toString();
        String s4 = tvS4.getText().toString();

        String allData = sensorName + ";" + s1 + ";" + s2 + ";" + s3 + ";" + s4 + ";";


        File ficheiro_dir = getApplicationContext().getDir("DirFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
        File ficheiro = new File(ficheiro_dir, FILE_NAME);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            //fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(ficheiro,true);
            fos.write(allData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));


            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + ficheiro.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(ficheiro.exists())
                Toast.makeText(this, "EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "NOT EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    SensorSelectedActivity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    ficheiro);
            String type = "text/plain";

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType(type);
            sharingIntent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(sharingIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting in log cat?

Comment: @Jayanth Fail to get file list com.example.apptest and  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array